# daterangepicker two different inputs

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

I have two different daterangepicker in the same form, because I need to have it in two inputs nor only in one.. So I initialize this with a class selector:
$('.daterange').daterangepicker({});

everithing works perfect, but I want to do change two both. If I select a range in the first one, when I open the second one I want to have the same range selected in the calendars. So I'm trying to do it in ON SHOW event

```
$('.daterange').daterangepicker()
.on('apply.daterangepicker' ,function(ev, picker) {
$('.scheduledStartGmt').val(picker.startDate.format(picker.format)).change();
$('.scheduledEndGmt').val(picker.endDate.format(picker.format)).change();
})
.on('show.daterangepicker' ,function(ev, picker){

$('.daterange').data('daterangepicker').setStartDate($('.scheduledStartGmt').val()); 
$('.daterange').data('daterangepicker').setEndDate($('.scheduledEndGmt').val());

});
```

Only changes the first one. How can I do it?

Comment: So your second date range picker will readonly ?

Comment: why don't you just put the value of the first date in your second datepicker?

Comment: no, I have two inputs one is StartDate and the second one is EndDate. The range is between two dates but you can edit clicking two either. Is like the daterangepicker of this web: https://www.booking.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i was facing the same problem but found the Solution, this may help you:

Have a look at my code:

```
    if($('#search_checkin, #search_checkout').length){
    // check if element is available to bind ITS ONLY ON HOMEPAGE
    var currentDate = moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY");

    $('#search_checkin, #search_checkout').daterangepicker({
        locale: {
              format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
        },
        "alwaysShowCalendars": true,
        "minDate": currentDate,
        "maxDate": moment().add('months', 1),
        autoApply: true,
        autoUpdateInput: false
    }, function(start, end, label) {
      // console.log("New date range selected: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' (predefined range: ' + label + ')");
      // Lets update the fields manually this event fires on selection of range
      var selectedStartDate = start.format('DD-MM-YYYY'); // selected start
      var selectedEndDate = end.format('DD-MM-YYYY'); // selected end

      $checkinInput = $('#search_checkin');
      $checkoutInput = $('#search_checkout');

      // Updating Fields with selected dates
      $checkinInput.val(selectedStartDate);
      $checkoutInput.val(selectedEndDate);

      // Setting the Selection of dates on calender on CHECKOUT FIELD (To get this it must be binded by Ids not Calss)
      var checkOutPicker = $checkoutInput.data('daterangepicker');
      checkOutPicker.setStartDate(selectedStartDate);
      checkOutPicker.setEndDate(selectedEndDate);

      // Setting the Selection of dates on calender on CHECKIN FIELD (To get this it must be binded by Ids not Calss)
      var checkInPicker = $checkinInput.data('daterangepicker');
      checkInPicker.setStartDate(selectedStartDate);
      checkInPicker.setEndDate(selectedEndDate);

    });

} // End Daterange Picker
```

please let me know if you want me to explain.

Comment: FYI, i also included moment.js to play with dates and also used in the above code.